# How to detect if file is completly copied PHP

Tags: php, file, upload, filesize, filetime

i have tried serval ways for how to detect if file is not yet complete and is still being copied.  but

```
    $filemtimeNOW   =   date("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($tempPath."files/". "test.csv"));
    sleep(20);
    $filemtimeLATER =   date("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($tempPath."files/". "test.csv"));
    echo   $filemtimeNOW . "<br>";
    echo   $filemtimeLATER . "<br>";
    sleep(10);
        if ($filemtimeNOW  == $filemtimeLATER)
        echo   $filemtimeNOW. "finished" ;
        else 
        echo   $filemtimeNOW. "still being copied" ;
```

RESTULT IS

1449338332
1449338332
1449338332 finished

even if the file is still uploading via ftp it shows the total filesize
i have also tried with datetime and still same problem
hopesomeone have idea

Comment: UP.....................

Answer (score 1):

You can try with filesize, not testes :

```
$filesizeNOW   =   filesize($tempPath."files/". "test.csv");
sleep(20);
$filesizeLATER =   filesize($tempPath."files/". "test.csv");
echo   $filesizeNOW . "<br>";
echo   $filesizeLATER . "<br>";
sleep(10);
    if ($filesizeNOW  == $filesizeLATER)
    echo   $filesizeNOW. "finished" ;
    else 
    echo   $filesizeNOW. "still being copied" ;
```

Comment: I have just tried
Warning: filesize(): stat failed for /home/..../test.csv in /home/.../scrap.php on line 21
January 01 1970 01:00:00.
January 01 1970 01:00:00.
January 01 1970 01:00:00.finished

Comment: done and the same

December 05 2015 20:25:14.
December 05 2015 20:25:14.
December 05 2015 20:25:14.finished

Comment: strange becouse i can see that when uploading the file it is increasing in the filezilla  but ow to get the modified date in realtime or something

Comment: Why do the code returns you a date as `filesize` returns an int ?

Comment: Now i removed the  date from the function
and got
14929056
14929056
14929056finished

Comment: i just want a way to know if the file is complete before i can use it.
becouse if it is not completly uploaded i will have a problem